# Почему не получается и открыть, и закрыть меню по 1 кнопке через чистый js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет : ) Пытался оформить функционал toggle, но как всегда что-то пошло не так.
Ни так:

```
settingsToggle.onclick = function () {
  let i = 0
  i++
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    settingsPopup.style.visibility = "visible"
  } else {
    settingsPopup.style.visibility = "hidden"
  }
}
```

Ни так не работает:

```
settingsToggle.onclick = function () {
  if (settingsPopup.style.visibility == "hidden") {
    settingsPopup.style.visibility = "visible"
  } else {
    settingsPopup.style.visibility = "hidden"
  }
}
```

Я так понимаю это так неосуществимо или все-таки опять ошибка в синтаксисе?

Comment: Почему бы просто для `settingsPopup` не дать класс допустим `settingsPopup--open`? Выйдет что-то `settingsPopup.classList.toggle("settingsPopup--open")` - всего одна строка.

Comment: @OliverPatterson тоже вариант кстати

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let i = 0;
settingsToggle.onclick = function () {
  if (++i % 2 == 0) {
    settingsPopup.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    settingsPopup.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
};
```

Comment: Заработало, но почему-то только 1е открытие происходить только на 2й клик, но я поменял на `i % 2 == 0` и все окей, конечно не понимаю почему так, но да ладно. Спасибо)

Comment: точнее на `i % 2 == 1`

Comment: @bluepuper Дело в начальной видимости/невидимости элемента. Она должна быть синхронизирована с начальным значением `i` или с условием.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const settingsToggle = document.querySelector('.settingsToggle')
const toggle = (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('toggle')
}
settingsToggle.addEventListener('click',toggle)
```

```css
.toggle{
    background-color: red;
}

.settingsToggle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="settingsToggle"></div>
</div>
```